# form submission not retaining values

Tags: php, forms

I have a functions page and my form page. My form is my register page and it has checks in it.(I posted around 30% of my code if more is needed ask me please)

Functionspage:

```
function validateRegister(){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = ucwords($key) . " field is required";
            $errflag = true;
        }
    }
        if(!empty($_POST['reg'])){
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $errmsgt_arr[] = "the provided email is not a valid email address";
         $errflagt = true;
     }
   }
    if(!empty($errflag)) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();  
    header("location: register.php");
    exit();

}
if(!empty($errflagt)) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR'] = $errmsgt_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: register.php");
    exit();

}
```

In my register page I have this form:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'functions.php';
session_start();
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
}

if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR']) >0 ) {
    foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR'] as $msg) {
        echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>';
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr>
<td>gebdatum</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>rijbewijs</td>

<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input name="reg" type="submit" value="Sign-up" class="btn2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['reg']))
{
    $register = new User();
    $register->Register();
}
unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
unset($_SESSION['ERRMSGT_ARR']);
?>
</form>
```

When I register it checks all the $_posts etc. When the form gets submitted successfully the `<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];?` line of code works. It echo's the previous values.

But when the errors display.The $_POST values doesn't retain anymore it just disappears.

I don't know what causes this problem. I'd love if someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Seems to be missing [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Read the PHP.net page and add it to your script.

Comment: I do have that code but I excluded it my bad. Edited my post

Comment: @vogomatix Do you see what else it may be?

Comment: Oh you're right I think. But how would I make a $_SESSION for all the outputs? and then retrieve it back?

Comment: @RyanVincent I've just tested it, and no it doesn't work. Still no retain of the values.

Comment: @RyanVincent I've tried multiple ways, either it doesn't retain values or I get the error: localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: I appreciate it a lot thanks :)! @RyanVincent

Comment: Yeah that's true. If you want I can post my whole code somewhere so you can see it? @RyanVincent

Comment: Here are a couple of scripts that work together to validate the input and loop around if error and call a routine when valid. You supply the 'register stuff...'. At pastebin.com: [Q36454747_functions.php](http://pastebin.com/uZ5yU7Ua). [Q36454747_register.php](http://pastebin.com/1rPj8a11). Run: `http://localhost/Q36454747_register.php`.

Comment: @RyanVincent This works like a charm. But there is 1 bug in it. The check for the email doesn't work properly. If the field isn't full it displays 2 errors. 1 with the : email field is required. and 1 with the: provided amil is not a valid email adress.

When you put it on pastebin you had the email array like this : $errmsgt_arr[] instead of $errmsg_arr[]. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you only changed $errmsgt to $errmsg? I had already done that. When the email adress field is empty, I get both errors displayed. The provided email is not a valid email adress and Email adress field is required. That's the problem atm.

Comment: @RyanVincent YES! this works perfect! Thank you alot!! How can I pay you ever back?!

Comment: @RyanVincent I've sent you a mail can you give a look?

Comment: @RyanVincent Did you receive my email?

Comment: Yes, got the email :) You never store the username as they enter it. You never check the entered username for an exact match. Why not? what if they have the `caps lock` on when entering the username - or press shift for their name etc. So, always store username in lowercase in the database after using `trim` to remove whitespace. And always convert username to lowercase on input. also, always `trim` input for username and password to remove leading and trailing whitespace. It should then work as you expect?

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for those tips I manage to fix this aswell. Because of you I got really far in my project and I'm really thankful for that!